# Cannot see icon/servers for PIA (Private Internet Access) on 17.10

Tags: networking, icons, vpn, 17.10

I have upgraded to 17.10 and I am am having problems with PIA. The PIA icon does not appear in the top bar.  I had this issue with 16.10 but could get around it by installing SimpleVPN which led to all the PIA VPN servers showing up when I right clicked the network icon.  Tis no longer happens and I have no idea how to configure PIA/Network VPN to get them to appear.

I have found a number of references to similar problems in Ask Ubuntu for 17.04 and I have applied all the suggestions/fixes.

I have the installed the latest version of PIA (pia-v74-installer-linux) which helped a bit.

The only thing that has done anything to help is to install topicon.  However, whilst the PIA icon now appears in the topbar when I right click it to see the servers all the text is displayed as small squares. Whilst I can guess at which option to choose based on my previous experience of where things appear in the list, it is less than optimal (understatement) I think the squares indicate I may be missing a required font, but I have no idea which one or how to install it.

Can anyone help me understand what it it I am doing wrong? I know there are lots of other PIA users using Ubuntu and I'm guessing/hoping I may just need to play with configuration options somewhere to get it up and running properly.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue after upgrading to Xubuntu 17.10 and I tried rebuilding the fonts without any luck, before I came across a solution that worked for me.

```
cd ~/.pia_manager/pia_tray_bin/
rm -r nw-linux-64
curl https://dl.nwjs.io/v0.26.0/nwjs-v0.26.0-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar -zx
mv nwjs-* nw-linux-64
mv nw-linux-64/nw nw-linux-64/pia_nw
```

Source: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/27543/ubuntu-mate-17-10-tray-menus-solved

P.S. I used the latest version, 0.26.0 of NW.js, but 0.24.0 which is used in the source I found also works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/phocean/TopIcons-plus which worked for me on Manjaro.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me!